# Why the increment step inside the for loop is being executed, since not all conditions were met?

Tags: c

I'm studying C using the "C Programming Language" book, and I got into character arrays (section 1.9) from chapter 1. This is the `getline()` function it presents:

```
/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Take the word `"Hi"` as example.

In my point of view, `s[1]` should be equal to `'\n'`, because the `i` should be only incremented when all conditions are met, however, when `c` is equal to `'\n'`, the `for` loop exits, and `i` should contain a value of `1` and not `2`.

So, why it is being incremented with only 2 of 3 conditions met?

I already tried using pre-increment operators and post-increments operators, and testing the `i` value inside certain lines of code.

Comment: The `++i` is executed at the *end* of each loop's iteration (if any).

Comment: `s[0]` wil be `'H'`, `s[1]` will be `'i'`, `s[2]` will be `'\n'` and `s[3]` will be `'\0'`.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the body of the loop statements? Like, the increment step will be executed besides the conditions stated between the semicolons?

Comment: The third part of the `for` loop (the increment) has nothing to do with the second part (the end condition).

Comment: `for(A;B;C){X}` is (roughly) equivalent to `A;while(B){X;C}`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, so the only difference is the execution or non-execution of the body. So that implies that before each next for loop that uses the same variable, it continue to contain the old value, leading to the importance of the initialization again?

Comment: The `for` loop is well explained in any text book.

Comment: `i` gets incremented in the loop for each character that is not a newline.  It starts at `0`, then gets incremented to `1` for `H`, then gets incremented to `2` for `i`.  Then the loop exits, and if there's a newline, the newline is stored in `s[2]`, and `i` gets incremented to `3`.  Then `'\0'` is stored in `s[3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop variable `i` is incremented at the end of the loop body.  You can write your `for`-loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
    s[i] = c;
```

as an equivalent `while`-loop:

```
i = 0;
while(i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

Also, I suggest you rename your function to not conflict with the exiting function of the same name.  Consider swapping the arguments so you can express how the `lim` and `s` variables are related and use `size_t` instead of `int` as negative `lim` probalby doesn't make sense:

```
size_t my_getline(size_t lim, char s[lim]);
```

The loop condition to `i < lim - 1` is wrong as may write 2 bytes after the loop which will overflow the buffer.  If `lim <= 0` you overflow the buffer.  if `lim < 1` you have undefined behavior as `c` is uninitialized.  I suggest you handle the newline in the loop like this, and only write the '\0' if `s` has room for at least 1 byte:

```
size_t my_getline(size_t lim, char s[lim]) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while(i < lim - 1) {
        int c = getchar();
        if(c == EOF) break;
        s[i++] = c;
        if(c == '\n') break;
    }
    if(lim) s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Actually, "lim" is a Symbolic Constant containing the value of 1000.

Comment: @mpriv8 You seem confused.  While you may have a symbol constant with the value 1000, and indeed use that in the call to `getline()`.   I am talking about how you use the parameter `lim` in the function to guard against buffer overflow, and how you have a logic error.

Comment: I'm a beginner to the C programming language haha, but thank you for the warning, however, I don't have a clue yet on what do you are trying to tell me, I only heard about buffer overflow when I was learning pentesting.

Comment: An array `s` of size `lim` is indexed from `0` to `lim - 1`.  In you code the `i` goes from to `lim - 2` (`i < lim - 1` is the same as `i <= lim - 2`).   Then after the loop you potentially add 2 characters which is `s[lim - 1] = '\n'` which is fine then `s[lim] = '\0'` which is one after the array and a buffer overflow.